# How do you delete all hidden and non-hidden files except one?

Tags: bash, git-bash, rm

How do you delete all hidden and non-hidden files except one in Bash?

Because I am creating a repository, and just now creating an update script.

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you want to delete all but one file? There might already be a tool for this. my guess is that you want to delete all known files apart from `.git`. Am I right?

Comment: mv file-to-keep /tmp; rm -r *; mv /tmp/file-to-keep .?

Comment: @JoshBeauregard All files, and git except an update script, because I need this for updating downloaded source code to a newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will delete everything in the current directory that you have permission to remove, recursively, preserving the file named by `-path`, and its parent path.

```
# remove all files bar one
find . -mindepth 1 -not -type d -not -path ./file/to/keep -exec rm -rf {} +

# then remove all empty directories
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rmdir -p {} + 2>/dev/null
```

`rmdir` will get fed a lot of directories it's already removed (causing error messages). `rmdir -p` is POSIX. This would not work without `-p`.

You can keep more files with additional `-path` arguments, and/or  glob patterns. The paths must match the starting point, i.e. `./`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) and [dot-globbing](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) features of Bash:

```sh
shopt -s dotglob extglob
cd /path/to/clean && rm !(file-name-to-keep)
```

This works by changing to the parent directory and -- if that was successful -- executing an `rm` command on an extended wildcard. That extended wildcard asks bash to expand all of the filenames (including those starting with a period, given `shopt -s dotglob`) except for `file-name-to-keep`.

Answer (score 0):

This would delete all files (not directories) in the current directory apart from "file-x":

```
rm `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v "^\./file-x\$"`
```

The find creates a list of all files (including hidden ones). The "grep -v" removes the line "./file-x" from that list.

Comment: That's going to break for filenames containing spaces. Also, `find` can exclude the wanted file: `find . -type f -not -name file-x -print0 | xargs -0 echo rm` (remove "echo" if it looks right)

Comment: I need to delete all files and directories except one file.